# Explicit formulae for $\binom{n}{1} \cdot 1^y+\binom{n}{2} \cdot (2)^y+\dots +\binom{n}{n}\cdot n^y $

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Is there any explicit formulae for

> $\binom{n}{1} \cdot 1^y+\binom{n}{2} \cdot (2)^y+\dots +\binom{n}{n}\cdot n^y $

> $\binom{n}{1}\cdot 1 \cdot 2^y+\binom{n}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 3^y+\dots+\binom{n}{n}\cdot n \cdot (n+1)^y $

I thought about it, also this is my own question, so I am not sure if there is an explicit formula or not. Thankyou!

Comment: You can write one down by repeatedly differentiating the binomial theorem $(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k$.

Comment: I think the same approach works for the second one too; multiply by $x$, differentiate; repeat $y$ times, finally differentiate once and substitute $x=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already received answers in comments.

If you like hypergeometric functions, you have a compact form. Writing a few of the
$$f_y=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k^y $$
$$f_4=n \, _4F_3(2,2,2,1-n;1,1,1;-1)$$
$$f_5=n \, _5F_4(2,2,2,2,1-n;1,1,1,1;-1)$$
$$f_6=n \, _6F_5(2,2,2,2,2,1-n;1,1,1,1,1;-1)$$ and the pattern is quite clear.